# How to persist namenode information in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have setup a single node cluster on my desktop. Problem is i can't keep my desktop running all the time. I do perform stop-all.sh, still later on when i perform start-all.sh , my namenode doesn't start up. And finally i have to do %hadoop namenode -format , to continue there by loosing all my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is seriously wrong. Please check what happen with image and edits file written by namenode. If they are ok - NameNode can start. 
Also... Last place to store NN data is HDFS - since you will get egg and chicken problem. W/o NN data HDFS is not accessible.

Comment: i added hadoop.tmp.dir in core-sites.xml and now everything is working normal. But why did it happen in the first place.
Hadoop takes /tmp/hadoop-${user.name} by default. In my case the access was denied. @david-gruzman does hadoop starts using the hdfs itself if the access to tmp file is denied?

Comment: I am almost sure HDFS will failed to start/operate if it does not have access to some dir it needs. Hadoop for sure, will not use HDFS instead of local ditectory. CDH even checks that dirs has exactly permissions they expect and do not works otherwise